# What is the scale of A # Minor / B flat minor? What does it look like in tab?

Tags: guitar, notation, scales, tablature

What is the  Guitar chord - lead  scale  of   A#  Minor /  B flat minor? I'd like to see what this scale looks like in tablature.
How do I play it?

Comment: If you know what the notes are for A minor, merely sharpen each of them. If you know the scale of B minor, flatten each of them!

Comment: @Tim im not getting   im newly  learning guitar

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you want to know? Your question doesn’t make a lot of sense. What do you mean by “lead scale”? A scale to play lead guitar with? A sharp minor and B flat minor *are* scales. And many chords can be built with them, not just one.

Comment: @trw im talking about  lead scale

Comment: i mean  tab  @trw..

Comment: You want to see what the A sharp/B flat minor scale looks like in tab?

Comment: yes    yes  exactly @trw

Comment: Why do you need this? It's not something a beginner usually has to play in - A#/Bbm. Even with editing, your question isn't clear.

Comment: May I ask - with full  respect: What sense does it make to ask for the a#- (b-) minor scale pattern before learning a-minor tab? would agree with The comment of Tim to transpose up the a- minor scale (or the b-minor down).

Then I thought there would be a problem with open strings in the first „position“. But there are other bends to start with, e.g. the 5th.

I think it would be better to understand the tuning system of a guitar and the pattern of any major scale in general.

Comment: This question is currently discussed on [meta](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3274/what-sense-does-it-make-to-ask-for-the-a-b-minor-scale-pattern-before-learn).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bbm chord

```
x13321
```

Bb minor pentatonic scale

You mention playing "lead". The most common "lead" scale in rock and blues is the minor pentatonic scale. A pentatonic scale is a scale with 5 tones. You can play other scales over a minor chord, but minor pentatonic is probably the place moost rock/blues players will start.

This one chord form and one scale isn't the full story about playing in `Bb` minor. It's just the basic starting point. When you get comfortable with it, you can try branching out to other chord voicings and other scales.

```
  1 2 3 4 

E-5-----7-
B---3---4-
G-7---1---
D-4---5---
A-1-----3-
E-5-----7-
```

Generally, you should refer to `Bb` minor instead of `A#` minor. It's a technical issue about 5 flats in `Bb` minor rather than 7 sharps in `A#`. It's a lot easier to read notation and handle common chord changes for `Bb` minor.

Comment: Just for other people's education, A pentatonic scale is **not** the same as the full natural, melodic, or harmonic minor scales.

Comment: what is  meaning  of  pentatonic ?

Comment: @jasmine, I added a note about the scale.

Comment: thanks u  @MichaelCurtis   let  me  try  in guitar

Comment: Sorry Michael, but that diagram is a bit confusing. You’re using natural minor scale degrees to show pentatonic note positions? I’ve never seen that before! If that’s the case, the 2 doesn’t belong and you’re missing a 4. (Both on the B string.)

Comment: @trw, thanks, I corrected the B string. Otherwise I put the scale degrees `1 b3 4 5 b7` on the strings. You can think of that as natural minor - and pentatonic as a gapped scale - or you can think of those numbers as the intervals above the tonic.

Comment: I've seen all kinds of labels on the strings. Identifying scale root and degrees or intervals is fairly common.

Comment: +1 It made sense after I studied it for a moment. It couldn’t be finger numbers. :)

Comment: @jasmine, I can add an explanation if you don't know how to read those tab diagrams, let me know

Comment: Do you find it a little odd that a beginner is already at A#/Bb in their playing?

Comment: Seemed a bit odd. I figured it was for a song they heard.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to play the B♭ minor scale on the guitar. Assuming you want the *natural* minor scale, this is one example of how to play it, shown in standard tablature:

```
——————————————————————————————-6-8-9-
————————————————————————-6-7-9——————-
————————————————————-6-8————————————-
—————————————-6-8-10—————————————————
———————-6-8-9———————————————————————-
—-6-8-9——————————————————————————————
```

If you want to end with B♭, don’t play the last two notes.

Note that there are other minor scales besides natural minor.

A♯ and B♭ are enharmonic notes, keys, and chords, so you would play them the exact same way. B♭ is by far more common because it’s more practical in standard notation.

It would be beneficial if you learned the *shape* of the scales on the guitar. You could then play that scale with any tonic note by shifting it up and down the fretboard.

The diagram below shows the spacing between the notes of the major and natural minor scales. (The “blue” notes, which are *not* part of those scales but often used in blues and rock music, are shown in blue.) The red notes are major roots. The green are minor roots. The yellow are other pentatonic notes. The gray are other additional diatonic notes. There are no fret numbers because this diagram can be seated at any fretboard position.

[image: Fretboard]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you learn what spacing is between the notes on a minor scale.  3 minor types are natural, harmonic, and melodic. These are available online many times over. Half steps are single frets two frets are whole steps. Sound them out. Ride up one string to find the pitches and compare that with convenient fingerings in one position. Theres nothing like self discovery. I will tell you the natural minor is down 1 and a half steps from the relative major using same notes.